# Flexbox doesnt take whole width when use overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

I am creating a grid using flexbox and I want to use overflow-x (there may be more columns than in the snippet below)
. However, I noticed that the bottom border for each row doesn't extend completely, ie, it doesnt take the whole width.... What is wrong with the css I am using?

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.gridHeader {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7dc;
}

.gridHeader .gridCell {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #334D5C;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.gridHeader .gridCell:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gridBody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.gridHeader .fa {
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gridHeader .fa-sort {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.gridHeader .fa-sort-asc,
.gridHeader .fa-sort-desc {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.sortable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gridRow {
  display: flex;
  min-width: calc(100% / 7);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #d2d7dc;
  border-style: solid;
  min-height: 50px; //max-height: 80px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.gridRow:hover {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.gridCell {
  min-width: calc(100% / 7);
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: break-word;
  text-align: center; //box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-all; //overflow:hidden;
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  border: 3px dashed #aaa;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: calc(100% / 7);
  background: #D1E5FA;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid ui-sortable">
  <div class="gridHeader">
    <div id="inline-actions" class="gridCell"></div>
    <div id="title" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="title">title<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="customer" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="customer">customer<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="price" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="price">price<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="calories" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="calories">calories<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="vegetarian" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="vegetarian">vegetarian<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="duedate" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="duedate">duedate<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridBody">
    <div class="gridRow" data-recordnumber="0">
      <div class="gridCell" data-recordnumber="0"><i id="edit" class="actions fa fa-pencil"></i><i id="delete" class="actions fa fa-trash"></i></div>
      <div class="gridCell">Chocolate Pancakes With Fruits</div>
      <div class="gridCell">Bilbo Baggins</div>
      <div class="gridCell">300</div>
      <div class="gridCell">1997.07</div>
      <div class="gridCell">true</div>
      <div class="gridCell">2017-07-04</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridRow" data-recordnumber="1">
      <div class="gridCell" data-recordnumber="1"><i id="edit" class="actions fa fa-pencil"></i><i id="delete" class="actions fa fa-trash"></i></div>
      <div class="gridCell">Cinnamon Sugar Fried Apples</div>
      <div class="gridCell">Frodo Baggins</div>
      <div class="gridCell">200</div>
      <div class="gridCell">1997.07</div>
      <div class="gridCell">true</div>
      <div class="gridCell">2017-07-06</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can fix it by adding border on grid cells but you will have to remove the margin

Comment: Flexbox is not made for tabular data layouts, table and grid are, so to make this work and have both header and body items aligned, they need a set width, either per column or equal. This will also make it easy to solve the border issue, so which solution do you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how `flex` is going to help to you if cell width might be different because

- you're not setting the same `width` for all cells, you're setting `min-width`.
- you're not setting `flex-shrink` to `0` for cells to avoid cell shrinking

So I would recommend you to switch to tables (you can achieve this without changing markup, via setting `display: table-row`, `display: table-cell` for corresponding elements and so on) if you're not going to set some fixed value for cell width.

So if you'll change

- `flex` layout to `table`
- `100%` replace with `100vw`
- move border definitions to cells
- change margin to paddings for table cells

this will work as expected:

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.gridHeader {
  display: table-row;
}

.gridHeader .gridCell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #334D5C;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.gridHeader .gridCell:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gridBody {
  display: table-row-group;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.gridHeader .fa {
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gridHeader .fa-sort {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.gridHeader .fa-sort-asc,
.gridHeader .fa-sort-desc {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.sortable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gridRow {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.gridRow:hover {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.gridCell {
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: calc(100vw / 7);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7dc;
  white-space: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  border: 3px dashed #aaa;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: calc(100vw / 7);
  background: #D1E5FA;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid ui-sortable">
  <div class="gridHeader">
    <div id="inline-actions" class="gridCell"></div>
    <div id="title" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="title">title<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="customer" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="customer">customer<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="price" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="price">price<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="calories" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="calories">calories<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="vegetarian" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="vegetarian">vegetarian<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="duedate" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="duedate">duedate<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridBody">
    <div class="gridRow" data-recordnumber="0">
      <div class="gridCell" data-recordnumber="0"><i id="edit" class="actions fa fa-pencil"></i><i id="delete" class="actions fa fa-trash"></i></div>
      <div class="gridCell">Chocolate Pancakes With Fruits</div>
      <div class="gridCell">Bilbo Baggins</div>
      <div class="gridCell">300</div>
      <div class="gridCell">1997.07</div>
      <div class="gridCell">true</div>
      <div class="gridCell">2017-07-04</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridRow" data-recordnumber="1">
      <div class="gridCell" data-recordnumber="1"><i id="edit" class="actions fa fa-pencil"></i><i id="delete" class="actions fa fa-trash"></i></div>
      <div class="gridCell">Cinnamon Sugar Fried Apples</div>
      <div class="gridCell">Frodo Baggins</div>
      <div class="gridCell">200</div>
      <div class="gridCell">1997.07</div>
      <div class="gridCell">true</div>
      <div class="gridCell">2017-07-06</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, another question though. I want to keep the gridHeader fixed. I tried with position: fixed, but that makes the gridHeader row longer the the gridBody...any idea?

Comment: @coffeeak As far as I know there is no easy pure CSS cross-browser solution for this. Also I suppose there were some questions here about this with Javascript solutions.

Answer (score 0):

just change `min-width` to `width` at `.gridCell`

```
.gridCell {
  width: calc(100% / 7); 
  ...
}
```

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.gridHeader {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d7dc;
}

.gridHeader .gridCell {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #334D5C;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.gridHeader .gridCell:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gridBody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.gridHeader .fa {
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gridHeader .fa-sort {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.gridHeader .fa-sort-asc,
.gridHeader .fa-sort-desc {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.sortable {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gridRow {
  display: flex;
  min-width: calc(100% / 7);
  background-color: #fff;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #d2d7dc;
  border-style: solid;
  min-height: 50px; //max-height: 80px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.gridRow:hover {
  color: #45B29D;
}

.gridCell {

  /* min-width: calc(100% / 7); */  
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: break-word;
  text-align: center; //box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-all; //overflow:hidden;
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  border: 3px dashed #aaa;
  height: 50px;
  min-width: calc(100% / 7);
  background: #D1E5FA;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid ui-sortable">
  <div class="gridHeader">
    <div id="inline-actions" class="gridCell"></div>
    <div id="title" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="title">title<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="customer" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="customer">customer<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="price" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="price">price<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="calories" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="calories">calories<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="vegetarian" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="vegetarian">vegetarian<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
    <div id="duedate" class="sortable gridCell ui-sortable-handle" title="Click on title to sort. Drag and drop to reorder." data-sort="nosort" data-header="duedate">duedate<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridBody">
    <div class="gridRow" data-recordnumber="0">
      <div class="gridCell" data-recordnumber="0"><i id="edit" class="actions fa fa-pencil"></i><i id="delete" class="actions fa fa-trash"></i></div>
      <div class="gridCell">Chocolate Pancakes With Fruits</div>
      <div class="gridCell">Bilbo Baggins</div>
      <div class="gridCell">300</div>
      <div class="gridCell">1997.07</div>
      <div class="gridCell">true</div>
      <div class="gridCell">2017-07-04</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridRow" data-recordnumber="1">
      <div class="gridCell" data-recordnumber="1"><i id="edit" class="actions fa fa-pencil"></i><i id="delete" class="actions fa fa-trash"></i></div>
      <div class="gridCell">Cinnamon Sugar Fried Apples</div>
      <div class="gridCell">Frodo Baggins</div>
      <div class="gridCell">200</div>
      <div class="gridCell">1997.07</div>
      <div class="gridCell">true</div>
      <div class="gridCell">2017-07-06</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```